# Center an image within a <section> with buttons below

Tags: html, css

I have a section where I wish to display an image that is rather large, in the middle of the page. By this I mean the middle of the image, in the middle of the section.

Prior to asking, I have tried the following snippets of code under in the image CSS.

```
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;

display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
vertical-align: middle

padding-top: 100px;

position: absolute;
top: 45%;
left: 45%
```

NOTE: Adding the position of "Absolute" followed by the left and top values, the image was to go to the above section, not staying on the second section. [image]

NOTE: Adding Padding to the CSS resulted in blank white space being produced above the section.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3L02tm2u/

Additional notes:

> Sections are of 100% width AND height
>
> Sections are below one another, so when padding is added to the second section, white space is created above this section.
>
> Summary: Wishing to have image completely in the middle of a section with buttons below the image.

Comment: when using **absolute**, the parent need to be **relative**

Comment: Would you consider flexbox for this layout? https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/3L02tm2u/4/

Comment: is this what you try to do ? https://jsfiddle.net/3L02tm2u/2/ (flex and margin )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Position relative to the parent will help absolute position elements inside it.

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/3L02tm2u/5/) is the working fiddle

[image]`

```
.section1{
   border:1px solid red;
   height:200px;
   width:200px;
   position:relative;
   margin:0 auto;
}

.image {
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.buttons-wrapper{
   position:absolute;
   width:100%;
   text-align:center;
   bottom:0;
   right:0
}
```

Comment: Is this a responsive technique?

Comment: @mp.jpeg .section1 width is here 200px, if you change it to 20% or 30%.then it becomes responsive now

Answer (score 1):

Flex seems to be a good way to achieve this :

```css
.image {
  margin: auto 50% 1em;
}

button {
  margin: 0 1em auto;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="section1">
  <img class="image" src="https://ak.picdn.net/assets/cms/97e1dd3f8a3ecb81356fe754a1a113f31b6dbfd4-stock-photo-photo-of-a-common-kingfisher-alcedo-atthis-adult-male-perched-on-a-lichen-covered-branch-107647640.jpg" alt="Cat" height="50" width="50">

  <button class="buttons">
   1
   </button>

  <button class="buttons">
   2
   </button>

  <button class="buttons">
   3
   </button>
</section>
```

For infos or older browser , the table-layout can also help:

```css
.image {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

button {
  margin: 1em;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="section1">
  <img class="image" src="https://ak.picdn.net/assets/cms/97e1dd3f8a3ecb81356fe754a1a113f31b6dbfd4-stock-photo-photo-of-a-common-kingfisher-alcedo-atthis-adult-male-perched-on-a-lichen-covered-branch-107647640.jpg" alt="Cat" height="50" width="50">

  <button class="buttons">
   1
   </button>

  <button class="buttons">
   2
   </button>

  <button class="buttons">
   3
   </button>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to work with the margin. Example if you have can write a css class for the image and the div like:

```
.divClass{
height: 40px; 
}

.imageClass{
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom:10px //not necessary if you work with px
}
```

if you want to work with % you may can write 2 class like:

```
.imgClass{
height: 80%;
margin-top:10%;
margin-bottm:10%;
}
```